# Литература по assembler

Tags: книги, ассемблер

Интересен очень язык assembler. Не знаю как подойти к его обучению, а именно нахожусь в поиске литературы. Интересна теоретическая база и практическая, то есть глава примеры и практические задания для закрепления материала. Также интересны статьи или может даже книги по связке в одной программе C++ и Assembler. Жду ваших советов.

Comment: У Зубкова неплохая книга по Асму есть. C я бы рекомендовал начинать учить после освоения ассемблера на уровне понимания адресации. Тогда проблем с указателями и ссылками будет меньше.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Ассемблер - это платформо-зависимый язык.  Просто так изучать Ассемблер не получится. Нужно определиться с той платформой, для которой вы собираетесь изучать Ассемблер. А также желательно выбрать конкретный транслятор Ассемблера.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow В данный момент хочу изучить для windows, а потом уже пытаться изучить под unix

Comment: язык ассемблера — это мнемоническая запись процессорных инструкций. архитектур процессоров — много. ещё больше вариантов этих архитектур — всяких «расширяющих наборов инструкций». потому и «диалектов» языка ассемблер — **очень** много. // и, кстати, к операционным системам это разнообразие имеет весьма малое отношение.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda  Тогда вам надо начинать с того, чтобы узнать, есть ли у Майкрософт отдельно устанавливаемый Ассемблер, и как им пользоваться, например, в среде MS Visual Studio или из командной строки.

Comment: @alexander barakin  На самом деле это имеет существенное значение. Например, какая модель памяти используется операционной системой, какие вызовы необходимо обязательно сделать перед передачей управления на ваш собственный код, какие системные службы можно использовать, какие соглашения о передачи параметров существуют для API  и.т.д.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, то, что вы описали, относится уже к практике использования, а к разнообразию **диалектов** (о котором я и писал) это имеет весьма малое отношение.

Comment: Могу посоветовать очень хороший ресурс wasm.ru.
На данный момент сайт очень давно модернизируется, но есть архив статей и форум. Начать стоит с ветки "Низкоуровневое программирование для дZенствующих" и далее "Уроки Iczelion'а". Ну и Тоненбаум "Архитектура ЭВМ" в догонку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"С.В. Зубков: Assembler. Язык неограниченных возможностей" - разбирается, в основном, асм под DOS, но, на мой взгляд, разбирается хорошо.

Answer (score 2):

А.Б. Крупник "Самоучитель ассемблер". Все доходчиво, под Windows, для новичка в самый раз. Рассматривается ассемблер masm32.

Answer (score 1):

Если бы передо мной стояла такая задача, то я бы начал с этой книги
http://habrahabr.ru/post/259505/

Comment: Как-то там электроники много, на мой взгляд. Книга скорее про микронтроллеры, нежели про x86-ассмеблер.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Меня это и отпугнуло, сейчас нашел книгу которую вы порекомендовали, полистаю посмотрю

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов А для каких еще задач сегодня может понадобиться Ассемблер?

Comment: reverse engineering, написание небольших кусков кода для ОС, высокопроизводительные вычисления.